# Setting input parameter for a method

Tags: web-services, abap

I have an object called `X` with a method `GET_BANK`, like in the picture below:

[image]

I want to call the function `GET_BANK` and I am trying to set the input parameter `BLZ` with a certain value.

**I don't quite understand the data structure that is presented here and how I can access it.**

At this point my code looks like this (simple version):

```
data: testobj type ref to ZCO_BLZSERVICE_PORT_TYPE .
data: input type ZGET_BANK .
input-BLZ = '10070000'.
```

I think the error that I am getting "The data object "INPUT" does not have a component called "BLZ"." is not relevant as I obviously have no idea on how to set the BLZ parameter.

**Edit:** Getting to BLZ can be done by chaining multiple parameters / objects:

`input-PARAMETERS-BLZ = '10070000'.`

Comment: I am calling a web service, I need to send some inputs to the call.

Comment: Sorry, my fault for not being clear.

Comment: trying to get a SAP stackexchange started for questions just like this. Check it out http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, your input data should refer to `TYPE ZGET_BANK_TYPE`. Try double-clicking the field with that content in the screen you showed to see whether it leads to a structure with a component named `BLZ`.

Comment: Good, I didn't know I can do the parameter chanining like `input-PARAMETERS-BLZ = '10070000'.`